# PHP ordered list from an array

Tags: php, arrays, list

Hi I'm trying to make an ordered list print out  from an array.
This is my code as of now:

```
    <?php


    $Salespeople = array(
    "Hiroshi Morinaga"=>57,
    "Judith Stein"=>44,
    "Jose Martinez"=>26,
    "Tyrone Winters"=>22,
    "Raja Singh"=>21);

    foreach ($Salespeople as $Salesperson) {
        echo key($Salespeople) . ": $Salesperson cars<br />";
        next($Salespeople);
    }
    ?>
```

the problem i have is that the outcome is this:

```
    Judith Stein: 57 cars
    Jose Martinez: 44 cars
    Tyrone Winters: 26 cars
    Raja Singh: 22 cars
    : 21 cars
```

How can i make it so it shows all the names and instead print out like this?

```
    Hiroshi Morinaga: 57
    Judith Stein: 44 cars
    Jose Martinez: 26 cars
    Tyrone Winter: 22 cars
    Raja Singh: 21 cars
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do want something like this?

```
foreach($Salespeople as $fullname => $cars) 
{
    echo $fullname . ": " . $cars . " cars<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach just simplier:

```
foreach ($Salespeople as $Salesperson => $Cars) {
    echo $Salesperson . ": $Cars cars<br />";
}
```

Comment: change `$Salespeople` on the last line to `$Salesperson` and it works perfectly - otherwise, all the names become `Array`.

Comment: Thank You very much guys, such big help!

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` will iterate over the list itself - you don't need to use `key` or `next`.

```
foreach ($Salespeople as $name => $number) {
    echo $name . ": $number cars<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could also use `array_map`:

```
 function echoSalesperson($v) { 
  echo $v . ": $Salesperson cars<br />" 
 }

 array_map($Salespeople,'echoSalesperson');
```